# "abline" doesn't work after "plot" when inside "with"

Tags: r, plot

I want to create a scatterplot and draw the regression line for a subset of a dataset. To give a reproducible example I'll use the CO2 dataset.

I tried this but the regression line doesn't appear for some reason

```
with(subset(CO2,Type=="Quebec"),plot(conc,uptake),abline(lm(uptake~conc)))
```

What is the correct way to give a command like this? Can I do it with a one-liner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to provide both your lines of code as a single R expression. The `abline()` is being taken as a subsequent argument to `with()`, which is the `...` argument. This is documented a a means to pass arguments on to future methods, but the end result is that it is effectively a black hole for this part of your code.

Two options, i) keep one line but wrap the expression in `{` and `}` and separate the two expressions with `;`:

```
with(subset(CO2,Type=="Quebec"), {plot(conc,uptake); abline(lm(uptake~conc))})
```

Or spread the expression out over two lines, still wrapped in `{` and `}`:

```
with(subset(CO2,Type=="Quebec"), 
     {plot(conc,uptake)
      abline(lm(uptake~conc))})
```

---

**Edit**: To be honest, if you are doing things like this you are missing out on the advantages of doing the subsetting via R's model formulae. I would have done this as follows:

```
plot(uptake ~ conc, data = CO2, subset = Type == "Quebec")
abline(lm(uptake ~ conc, data = CO2, subset = Type == "Quebec"), col = "red")
```

The `with()` is just causing you to obfuscate your code with braces and `;`.

Comment: Awesome suggestion in your "edit".  That's by far the correct way.

Comment: It's just that I don't like to give more than once a set of several restrictions. It might be dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

From `?with`: `with` ... evaluates `expr` in a local environment created using `data`.  You're passing `abline()` via `...`.  You need to do something like this:

```
with(subset(CO2,Type=="Quebec"),{plot(conc,uptake);abline(lm(uptake~conc))})
```

Answer (score 2):

Gavin and Joshua offer good solutions to your immediate problem; here's the equivalent plot using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(conc, uptake, data = CO2[CO2$Type == "Quebec" , ]) + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```